# c# how to find negative values in string and convert it?

Tags: c#, string

i get strings like this:

```
[(0 +-0,01)*(0,724-0) +(-0,01 +-17,982)*(0,725-0,724) +(-17,982 +-17,983)*(1,324-0,725) +(-17,983 +-30,587)*(1,323-1,324) +(-30,587 +-30,587)*(-0,004-1,323) +(-30,587 +0)*(0--0,004)]*0,5
```

i have to convert it in a way that --xx,xx or +-xx,xx will be set in brackets -(-xx,xx) or +(-xx,xx)

like this:

```
[(0 +(-0,01))*(0,724-0) +(-0,01 +(-17,982))*(0,725-0,724) +(-17,982 +(-17,983))*(1,324-0,725) +(-17,983 +(-30,587))*(1,323-1,324) +(-30,587 +(-30,587))*(-0,004-1,323) +(-30,587 +0)*(0-(-0,004))]*0,5
```

but i have no idea to do this.

Comment: You could use regex for find all the numbers with the `-` before and than wrap them into the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ... 

  string source =
    "[(0 +-0,01)*(0,724-0) +(-0,01 +-17,982)*(0,725-0,724) +(-17,982 +-17,983)*(1,324-0,725) +(-17,983 +-30,587)*(1,323-1,324) +(-30,587 +-30,587)*(-0,004-1,323) +(-30,587 +0)*(0--0,004)]*0,5";

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(?<=[+-])-[0-9]+(\,[0-9]+)?", "($&)");

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  [(0 +(-0,01))*(0,724-0) +(-0,01 +(-17,982))*(0,725-0,724) +(-17,982 +(-17,983))*(1,324-0,725) +(-17,983 +(-30,587))*(1,323-1,324) +(-30,587 +(-30,587))*(-0,004-1,323) +(-30,587 +0)*(0-(-0,004))]*0,5
```

Here we look for `(?<=[+-])-[0-9]+(\,[0-9]+)?` pattern:

```
  (?<=[+-]) - look ahead for + or -
          - - "-" 
     [0-9]+ - one or more digit in 0..9 range - integer part
(\,[0-9]+)? - optional fractional part: comma then one or more digit in 0..9 range
```

Each match we wrap into `(..)` - `"($&)"`

Comment: Thank you for the RegEx tip. The result is perfect! I had experimented with it myself, but had major problems with the correct syntak